# SPO: Show Autocomplete Filter WP results as Title field values but filtering from another field's value

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, filter

I am using an autocomplete filter customized in the HTML Form WP. When a user begins typing the name of a Company (i.e. **Title** field from the **Companies** list), all matching results autopopulate as the user types. Once the user clicks the Search button, all LVWPs on that page are filtered by the Title field of the Companies List.

I want to change this code so that all LVWPs are filtered by the field **companySubgroup** from the Companies list.

HOWEVER, I still want the search autocomplete results to display matching values from the Title field in the Companies list.

Below, you can see the filter script.

1. Companies: The name of the list
2. ows_Title: The Title field
3. tagsAuto: ID of the search results/search bar element

The filter script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var soapEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soapenv:Body> <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>Companies</listName><viewFields><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/> </ViewFields></viewFields> </GetListItems> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>";
        //Make a call to the List WebService using the SOAP envelope described above.
        //The URL is fixed to a Specific Site Root.  Feel free to change this
        //to your own fixed root or do some jscript voodoo to figure out where
        //Of course in 2010 you can do this with the Client Object Model, or hit
        //the list rest Service and return json, so enabling jsonp cross site calls.
        $.ajax({
            url: "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            success: function(xmlResponse) {
                var domElementArray = $("z\\:row", xmlResponse);
                var dataMap = domElementArray.map(function() {
                    return {
                        value: $(this).attr('ows_Title'),
                        id: $(this).attr('ows_Title')
                    };
                });
                var data = dataMap.get();

                //Find the Sharepoint Portal Search Box (this is a poor selector, but it is not properly named by sharepoint, well it is but INamingContainer gets in the way)    
                $("#tagsAuto").autocomplete({
                    source: data
                });
            }

        }); //.ajax   

    }); //docReady
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add a CAML Query in soapEnv variable to filter based on companySubgroup field, here is the modified complete code for your reference:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var soapEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soapenv:Body> <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>Companies</listName><viewFields><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/> </ViewFields></viewFields><query><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='companySubgroup' /><Value Type='Text'>subGroup2</Value></Eq></Where></Query></query> </GetListItems> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>";
        //Make a call to the List WebService using the SOAP envelope described above.
        //The URL is fixed to a Specific Site Root.  Feel free to change this
        //to your own fixed root or do some jscript voodoo to figure out where
        //Of course in 2010 you can do this with the Client Object Model, or hit
        //the list rest Service and return json, so enabling jsonp cross site calls.
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://zheguo.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            success: function(xmlResponse) {
                var domElementArray = $("z\\:row", xmlResponse);
                var dataMap = domElementArray.map(function() {
                    return {
                        value: $(this).attr('ows_Title'),
                        id: $(this).attr('ows_Title')
                    };
                });
                var data = dataMap.get();

                //Find the Sharepoint Portal Search Box (this is a poor selector, but it is not properly named by sharepoint, well it is but INamingContainer gets in the way)    
                $("#tagsAuto").autocomplete({
                    source: data
                });
            }

        }); //.ajax   

    }); //docReady
</script>
```

I'm filtering the field with "subGroup2" for example and autocomplete will only show the field meets the condition:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I should have specified earlier that 'companySubgroup' is a text field. For example, if the Title field value was "YouTube", the companySubgroup would be "Google". There are thousands of different values in the companySubgroup field. Is it possible to set this up for a text field instead of a choice field?

Comment: I have updated the CAML for filtering with Single Line Text field, please check.

Comment: Subgroup2 is a variable not a static value. Ideally, what should happen is the user enters a company name. The filter autosuggest shows the value of the Title field in the results. When the user selects the company of their choice based on the Title field, the LVWPs on the page should be filtered based on the value of the subgroupCompany column. The end result is the filtering LVWPs with values matching the subgroupCompany value NOT the Title field value

Comment: Didn't understand clearly.... so you have list web part in the page and want to pass the  filter value based on the subgroupCompany ?

Comment: As your comment above is concerning about the field type, right ?

Comment: Exactly...WHILE the autosuggest dropdown shows the value of Title column.

Comment: From the code snippet, it's only the auto complete logic, I modified it to filter based on subgroup based on description. If want to have filter to LVWP, I think should be pass with Url Filter...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102843/discussion-between-thejdscott-and-jerry-msft).